# How to a parse a string into a float with three decimal points in java

Tags: java, floating-point

I know there is a way of forcing a float to have 3 decimal points, but how do I make a string representation "4.00000009" retain 3 decimal points after I turn it into a float? `Float.parseFloat()` rounds it to 4.0.  Not using extra libraries would be ideal.

Comment: What's the problem there exactly? 4.0 = 4.000

Comment: `s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(".") + 4)`

Comment: It's simply a requirement that I have to have 3 decimal points, regardless of the equivalence in values.

Comment: @DannyLiang Can you elaborate? As Joseph said, 4.0 = 4.000. A string representation of a `float` can have a specific format, a `float` doesn't.

Comment: substring would just turn it into another string with the correct rounding correct? I need a float

Answer (score 1):

If you're guaranteed that the String is properly formatted, you can take a substring based on the index of the decimal.

Alternatively, you can parse it, multiply by a thousand, round it, and divide it by a thousand.

However, this is going to be bad for you in the long run. Floating point numbers don't fare so well when exact values are needed. Consider BigDecimal instead.

Answer (score 1):

This utility method takes a `String` and turns it into a `float` with 3 decimals places:

```
public static float getFloat(String s) {
    BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(s);
    decimal = decimal.setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return decimal.floatValue();
}
```

Comment: BigDecimal is the answer